# How to hide toolbar on right side?

Tags: shortcut

[image]
Hi, how do I hide the highlighted tollbars without hiding the ones at the bottom? I tried space+shift but it hides both of them.

Comment: You can click and drag the small triangle in the corner of the windows (toolbars) to collapse them. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/interface/window_system/tabs_panels.html https://youtu.be/4q6mLdO1E4Q

Comment: That doesn't work. It just makes duplicate toolbars within the area. And the video doesn't hide the toolbars I highlighted in red.

Comment: Keep the courser in 3D window and press ctrl+spacebar it will hide all the windows. Its toggle key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click and drag the corner triangles in the direction you want them to collapse.
This might help.
[image]

Comment: this SHOULD work.. I can slide the panel down, but can't slide my 3D view to the right. I would record my screen but I don't have the software/equipment.

Comment: Try collapsing the Dope sheet and timeline first, and then perform the steps mentioned in my answer. Blender's youtube channel has some good beginner videos regarding this like this one https://youtu.be/Yb00Tuv0Rhw?t=397

Comment: I think I did that somehow by mistake and it suddenly worked. Tried YT but didn't see one that specifically mentioned my problem. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Actually, it is not you fault since many beginners suffer with the same problem like yours because blender's interface is not that intuitive in this regard. I would suggest you to spend some time practising collapsing/expanding windows.

Answer (score 3):

There is another way. You can also do this:

[image]

Comment: This is the point. You can't drag a panel over a junction between two other panels.